# cadena de conexion en web api .net core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Estoy haciendo una web con .NET core, ya venía acostumbrado a que la conexión a la base la hacía accediendo al `web.config`:

```
string conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionsString["LaConexion"].ToString();
```

Tengo un proyecto web api con .NET core y lo más parecido que veo es un archivo llamado: `appsettings.json`

¿Cómo podría crear hay mi cadena de conexion y cómo acceder a ella ?

Les agradezco.

Comment: Saludos bro, hay varias cosas que han cambiado, te sugiero que le des una visita a mi blog http://fredyfx.com/blog/ que contiene una serie de 5 publicaciones donde hago una webapi desde cero, a pura línea de comandos conectada con EF Core y un cliente sencillo en vue.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings):

En el appsettings.json tienes algo así:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

Y en los servicios conectas de esta manera:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
}
```

Te sugiero que le des una visita a http://fredyfx.com/blog que contiene una serie de 5 publicaciones donde hago una webapi desde cero, a pura línea de comandos conectada con EF Core conectado a PostgreSQL y un cliente sencillo en vue.js